# Managing leaderboard in unity with firebase

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, unity-game-engine

I want to save player score into firebase database I write this code and make a post request in JSON format it neither priting error nor adding data into server . each time www.text brings brings unique response like this

> {"name":"-KQ-0awfeGNuapdD-5AR"}

what i am doing wrong. how can i post user score on firebase database. Remeber i didn't make any key on database. I just allow anonymous to enter data in DB

```
        //Firbase Database URL
        string url = "https://xyz.firebaseio.com/.json";
        WWWForm objForm = new WWWForm();

        //Adding Data
        objForm.AddField("playerName", name);
        objForm.AddField("score", score);
        objForm.AddField("scoreDate", DateTime.Now.ToString());

        //Making Header
        Dictionary<string, string> objDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        objDict.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");

        //Converting FormData into JSON-- necessary for firebase post
        string jsonConvertedForm = JsonUtility.ToJson(objForm);

        byte[] bytePostData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonConvertedForm);
        WWW www = new WWW(url, bytePostData, objDict);
        yield return www;

        if (www.error == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Adedd ::" + www.text );

        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Error ::" + www.error);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, that is the expected response of your request.

The response depends on the header you are using. Please refer to this documentation:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/

You are doing a data-pushing-request as you use **POST** header on your Http request. If you check your database through Firebase console, the data should have been saved under the generated key you get from the response.

If that is not what you want, you should try the other available Firebase request that suit your need.

Comment: Ok but nothing found on database also i i pull data then getting null

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan I could not test your data-to-json conversion part as I don't have that JsonUtility library you are using. So omitting that part, I have tested your code (I sent manually written json for replacement) and it works just fine here. Have you checked again on your script whether the sent string is a valid json?